# Array w/Nested For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I was doing a project earlier that consisted of many index/matches. I personally love nested loops, so I wanted to see if I could implement it this time around. My nested loop consists of i and j, where my third and most outer loop is my x variable, which gets placed inside my (Application.index). I've never done three loops so I'm not sure if this is possible. The error I am getting is, "application-defined or object-defined error".

Thanks,
SD

```
    Dim i%, j%
    Dim j&
    Dim myArr%(0 To 5)
    'myArr = Array(2, 1, 17, 18, 6, 16)
    'For x = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
    myArr(0) = 2
    myArr(1) = 1
    myArr(2) = 17
    myArr(3) = 18
    myArr(4) = 6
    myArr(5) = 16
    For x = 0 To 5
        For i = 2 To shSS.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
            For j = 1 To 16
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j) = Application.IfError(Application.Index(shRoster.Columns(x), Application.Match(shSS.Range("D" & i + 1), shRoster.Columns(4), 0)), "-")

            If shSS.Cells(i, 11) = "Internal" Then
                shCV.Cells(i, 10) = "Y"
            Else
                shCV.Cells(i, 10) = "N"
            End If

            Next j
        Next i
    Next x
```

Comment: Hello, if this is the entirety of your code, you should be getting errors for all occurrences of those sheet objects as we cannot see them being defined and set. shSS shRoster and shCV are never defined or set in this piece of code.

Comment: Hi, yes I've declared everything, the part I've added here is just a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j) = _
     Application.IfError(Application.Index(shRoster.Columns(x), _
     Application.Match(shSS.Range("D" & i + 1), shRoster.Columns(4), 0)), "-")
```

you can do something like:

```
Dim m

m = Application.Match(shSS.Range("D" & i + 1), shRoster.Columns(4), 0)

If Not IsError(m) Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value = shRoster.Columns(x).Cells(m)
Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value = "'-"
End If
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response. I've never seen it written like that, so thank you. Not sure if it was a helpful tip, or to solve the problem, but the code still doesn't run.

Comment: I was trying to give you a more manageable approach, but "doesn't run" doesn't help me understand the actual specific thing that's happening when you run this.  Do you get an error? If Yes, what is the error, and which line is highlighted when you click Debug?

Comment: Never mind, I forgot that `IIf()` doesn't short-circuit (always evaluates but the True and False parts)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention which line highlights. The error I get is, "application-defined or object-defined error", and the highlighted part is
```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j) = Application.IfError(Application.Index(shRoster.Columns(x), Application.Match(shSS.Range("D" & i + 1), shRoster.Columns(4), 0)), "-")
```

Comment: Didn't work. Still the same error. It stops right after the first If statement.. Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value = shRoster.Columns(x).Cells(m)

Comment: Hi Tim, would you be able to help me out still? I haven't had any luck solving it yet.

Comment: I can help if you can update your question and add in an explanation (in simple steps) of what the intent of your code is - what is it intended to do exactly?  In your code you have declared both `j%` and `j&` so this would not compile.  What is shSS  shRoster and shCV?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for everyone for taking their time at looking at it.